# Manually reallocating array of objects in c++

Tags: c++, arrays

I'm trying to reallocate array of object, but I'm getting segmentation fault .

This is the code:

Array.h

```
class Array
{

private:

    int * _Array;
    int length;
    int id;

    Array(int size, bool insert);
    static Array** allsArrays;
    static size_t sizeAll;
    static int amountOfArrays;

public:
    Array();
    Array(int size);
    Array(const Array& source); 

};
```

Array.cpp

```
int Array::amountOfArrays=0;
size_t Array::sizeAll=10;
Array** Array::allsArrays= new Array*[sizeAll];
Array Array::intitialsArray(0, false);

//constructor
Array::Array(int size, bool insert)
{
    if(size != 0)
    {
       sArray = new int [size];

        for(int i=0; i<size; i++)
        {
            sArray[i]=0;
        }
    }
    else
        sArray = NULL;

    length = size;
    id=0;
    if(insert == true)
    {
        insertToAllsArr(*this);
        amountOfArrays++;
        id = amountOfArrays;
    }

}


//the part that crashes, part of insertToAllsArr function

    //realloc
    if(sizeAll < amountOfArrays)
    {
        int oldSize=sizeAll;
        sizeAll += 10;
        Array **tmp=new Array*[sizeAll];
        for( i=0;i<(int)sizeAll;i++)
        {
           *tmp = &intitialsArray;
            if(i < oldSize)
            {
                 *tmp = *allsArrays;
                 ++allsArrays;
            }

            ++tmp;
        }

        for(i=0; i< (int)sizeAll ; i++ ,--tmp);
        for(i=0 ; i< oldSize ; i++, --allsArrays);

        allsArrays= new Array*[sizeAll];

        for( i=0;i<(int)sizeAll;i++)
        {
            *allsArrays = *tmp;
            ++allsArrays;
            ++tmp;
        }

    }
```

When I try to access allArrays from another function I get the segmentation fault.
What am I doing wrong?
(for those of you who might ask why am I not using std, I can't because of my copy constructor)
Thank you.

Comment: Usage of `std::array` or `std::vector` instead of plain C-style arrays might be more appropriate for C++. Nevertheless, using a static array to keep the data for all class instances isn't a very clever design idea!

Answer (score 1):

You are incrementing `allsArrays` and apparently not reseting it back to it's original value. You do that in the first loop but not in the second (it seems).

This is seriously ugly code. I would look to clean it up. You don't need two loops to copy values from one array to another, you don't need a tmp array, you don't need to mess with pointer increments like that. You also look to have at least two memory leaks.